# Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

From morning itself I faced the same error while Archive my project in Xcode. I tried many things from Stack Overflow answers also. They did not work though. How can I upload my application to the store?

In apple developer portal all my certificates are in active also.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Versioning System - Apple Generic enabled in your xcodeproj file?

Comment: Versioning System means, Sorry I have no idea about it.

Comment: It is clear in your image, both having different certificates, just make them same for both your parent app and embedded binary.